# How to use REST API to execute Map-Reduce Task?

Tags: apache-hadoop

Let's say I have one Text File (Size 1 GB). I want to search particular word from file and if it is found the Line number should be returned.

I can Execute my java program using command line in linux. But what I want is some Interface using REST API.

When I submit that word in GUI(My Interface) and submit request it should be able to call HDFS , commands should be provided by itself and it should return me the result.

How Can you approach this problem ? 
(I have very primitive knowledge about REST API)

Referred

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#ParameterDictionary[]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA

Comment: You are confusing two completely different types of systems.  A REST API (or API of any sort) applies to a software library that you call inside your code (Java, C++, Python, or whatever).  Separately, there are systems that perform Map-Reduce on data stored in HDFS (e.g. Hadoop).  Typically, there are intermediary systems (e.g. Hive) that interpret your query and execute it on the designated infrastructure (e.g. Hadoop).  I suggest that you read/watch tutorials on Hadoop/Hive (or similar), and don't think about REST API in that context.